# Unable to spawn Process using Anaconda multiprocess package

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi i am running one use case of Python Snowpark , it is specific to running lots of data loads in parallel. I have close to 42 tables which are loaded from SnowFlake.AccountUsage Views , The data into these tables are independent of each other so i tried to use Snowpark python library to do parallel data load using multiprocess package library. However when i ran this code from my laptop the code ran successfully but same code failed in Snowflake machine ; looks like Snowflake has designed its warehouses to not allow to fork/spawn the process for parallel processing. Do you have any thoughts on how to do the parallel data loading without using multiprocess package.

This is architectural level question, I request you not to close this query without inputs from architects.

The Error Message I am getting it

> "/usr/lib/python_udf/1439992e4e54a095348cc1d96f9448a9579f940638c334772ebfeb71ef5b03e0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/popen_fork.py",
> line 70, in _launch self.pid = os.fork() PermissionError: [Errno 1]
> Operation not permitted in function TEST_SNOWPARK with handler run

```
from multiprocess import Process
from snowflake.snowpark import Session

TransactionDataLoadSqlList=["""INSERT OVERWRITE INTO  DB.SCHEMA.T_STAGES  SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.STAGES" """]
# There are mutiple insert statements like this but for ex i have taken here only one
    main()
         processes=[]  
            try:  
                
                print(" Multi-processing started")
    
        
                for TSqls in  TransactionDataLoadSqlList:
                    # print(TSqls)
        
                    p=Process(target=RunAtSnowflake,args=[Session,TSqls])
                    
                    p.start()
                    processes.append(p) 
                
                for process in  processes:
                    process.join()
            
                print(" Multi-processing finished")
            except BaseException as err:
                print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}") 
                
                raise
    
         def RunAtSnowflake(Session,Query):
            Session.sql(Query).collect()      
            return "SUCCESS" 
            


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main(Session)
```

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by “failed”? What happened, were there any error messages, if you look in Snowflake query history did anything run? Also, please can you update your question with the relevant section(s) of your code?

Comment: Hi @NickW added the error message that i have received from Snowflake Python Procedure Run, also attached is code here the code is wrapped in Snowflake Python Procedure

Comment: @NickW I realized that Snowflake doesn't give permission on its warehouse  to spawn/fork process , my precise query is how do i perform or mimick similar scenario without using multiprocess package.

Comment: Can you describe the environment you are trying to run this in? A stored procedure?

Comment: Hi @Felipe Hoffa, yes all the code is wrapped inside Snowflake python procedure and created as in-line procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about running async queries.

Outside Snowpark, with the Snowflake Python connectors you can do this:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html?#performing-an-asynchronous-query

```py
conn = snowflake.connector.connect( ... )
cur = conn.cursor()
# Submit an asynchronous query for execution.
cur.execute_async('select count(*) from table(generator(timeLimit => 25))')
```

Inside Snowpark, as a stored procedure: Currently this is not supported, but stay tuned - as it's a feature that the eng team would like to implement.

As an alternative, I tried Scala with Snowpark:

```scala
// https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-scala.html

import com.snowflake.snowpark._

object Procedure {
  def main(session: Session): String = {
    var rows = session.sql("select 'Hello, Scala!'").async.collect();
    return rows.getResult()(0).getString(0);
  }
}
```

That one throws an exception "Async execution not supported in current context" - which is another way of saying, we'll need to wait to get async queries inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe Hoffa for your elaborate answer, if at this juncture I have to implement then one of the option I have is Snowflake connector for python.  I am thinking of porting this into azure functions , what's your thought?

Comment: That could work! Especially if you need it now, but waiting will bring async to stored procedures 